# Build CyanogenMod For Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 ("kenzo") Error CM13

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

Export includes file: frameworks/base/native/android/Android.mk -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_intermediates/export_includes Notice file: frameworks/base/libs/storage/NOTICE -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib64/libstorage.a.txt Notice file: frameworks/base/libs/storage/NOTICE -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj/NOTICE_FILES/src//system/lib/libstorage.a.txt 
Export includes file: frameworks/base/libs/input/Android.mk -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libinputservice_intermediates/export_includes 
Export includes file: frameworks/native/services/sensorservice/Android.mk -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libsensorservice_intermediates/export_includes make: * No rule to make target '/media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libtime_genoff_intermediates/export_includes', needed by '/media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_servers_intermediates/import_includes'. Stop. make: * Waiting for unfinished jobs.... 
Export includes file: system/core/libsuspend/Android.mk -- /media/hoangkhoatv/231BD04C2A9465BC/Android/android/system/out/target/product/kenzo/obj_arm/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libsuspend_intermediates/export_includes

make failed to build some targets (10:58 (mm:ss))

Comment: put some description on what you're trying to do, what your env details are, etc. and ask this in [ANOTHER Stackexchange site](http://android.stackexchange.com/?tags=cyanogenmod)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error too. It means that you've skipped the step of extracting proprietary blobs from the device, libtime_genoff.so is one of such blobs

Connect the device via adb and run device/xiaomi/kenzo/extract-files.sh script. The blobs and makefiles will appear in vendor/xiaomi/kenzo/ and make the build finish.

Alternatively get the blobs from somewhere else, e.g. github.com/TheMuppets